# RaptorQ open source implemention

Tags: signal-processing, linear-algebra, codec, telecommunication, forwarderrorcorrection

Does anybody know of any mature open source implementation of RaptorQ (RFC6330)?
If not, would anybody be interested in joining working on an open source project to build a full featured RaptorQ codec in C99?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like there's a recent effort to write one in Java.

https://github.com/openrq-team/OpenRQ